# How is lambda calculated in this lagrangian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, economics

[image]

It seems some steps are being skipped in this explanation of this lagrangian. I understand the setup but how does this lamda=sqrt(c1c2) come into place?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write donwn the score equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c_1} &= \frac{\sqrt{c_2}}{2\sqrt{c_1}}-\lambda = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{c_2}{c_1}} = 2\lambda \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c_2} &= \frac{\sqrt{c_1}}{2\sqrt{c_2}}-\frac{\lambda}{1.05} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{c_1}{c_2}} = \frac{2\lambda}{1.05} \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} &= 100-c_1-\frac{c_2}{1.05} = 0 \Leftrightarrow c_1+\frac{c_2}{1.05} = 100\\
\end{aligned}
$$

SO, it seems that there is a typo in the original document; it should be $2\lambda$, but the solution $(c_1, c_2)$ will be the same: $c_1 = 50, c_2 = 52.5$